# Oauth2 provider (Doorkeeper?) being an Oauth2 consumer (Devise+OmniAuth) for login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, oauth-2.0, omniauth, doorkeeper

Oauth2 is driving me crazy.

Currently, my Rails application authenticates users through Facebook, and soon other Oauth2 providers, thanks to the beauty of Devise & OmniAuth. User can't sign in with login & password.

But as my application is mainly an API, I also want it to act as an Oauth2 provider, to protect data.

Thus, the user sign in with Facebook -> my application obtain an Access Token, and then -> provides the user a new Access Token to access my API -> my AngularJS application (or any other app) uses this token to access my API without knowing Facebook or Google Access Token.
It looks like I need to forward Oauth2 token to client with a custom provider.

I discovered doorkeeper gem... but I can't understand how to articulate it with Devise & Omniauth.

I found many partial answers here, but not a complete one.

I will appreciate any help, good tutorial, or more complete answers.

Comment: I can only show you an example app where I'm using it: https://github.com/TecnologieDemocratiche/TecnologieDemocratiche and as client: https://github.com/TecnologieDemocratiche/doorkeeper-devise-client

Comment: I'll start to implement a solution like this.. If I succeed I call tell you how to do it.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simple tutorial to get you started. Thanks to Andrea! 
1. Server Application (Devise + Doorkeeper) 
http://dev.mikamai.com/post/110722727899/oauth2-on-rails 
2. Client Application (Ominauth-oauth2) 
http://dev.mikamai.com/post/112508735689/oauth2-on-rails-the-client-application 
P.S. Minor Errata! 
1. When you generate the APP_ID and SECRET_ID for the client application from the server application - using `http://localhost:3000/oauth/applications/new` - enter the callback url `http://localhost:3001/auth/doorkeeper/callback` 
 
Or, if you see this after the error, go back to `http://localhost:3000/oauth/applications/` and edit the callback url. 
 We can't use  `http://localhost:3001/doorkeeper/callback` because this is not the route the tutorial is using from the Client Application. 
2. In the client application include the callback action definition as below and change the to_json method to as_json.

## ../oauth-client/app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  def authentication_callback
    auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    render json: auth.as_json
  end

end
```

Cheers!

Comment: One could say that Doorkeeper gem is an OAuth2 server implementation and OmniAuth gem is an OAuth2 client implementation?

Comment: Why do you need a separate server to consume the provider? Can't you technically have the authentication in the same project as the provider and then swap out the authentication mechanism from devise's username/password to OmniAuth.